# Classic asp function like php's parse_str()

Tags: php, vbscript, asp-classic

Is there any equivalent for php's parse_str in classic asp ?

I have a string like this: "key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3", and I need to convert it to a an array or similar structure so I can use it like a('key1') or something like that.
In php I do like this:

```php
parse_str(str_replace(",", "&", str_replace(", ", "&", $dn)), $arr);
```

How can I do this in classic ASP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no commas in your keys/values, you can use `Split()` to separate the string into an array of key/value pairs:

```vb
a = Split(s, ",")
```

Then you can further split each element on `=` to get the key and value separately:

```vb
For Each i In a
    a2 = Split(i, "=")
    ' Now a2(0) = key, a2(1) = value
Next
```

You won't be able to access it via "key" without using something like a Dictionary object, however.

Answer (score 0):

I personally tried this and works for me.

```
s = "key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3"
kp = Split(s, ",")
Set d=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim d

For Each i In kp
   kp2 = Split(i, "=")
   d.Add Trim(kp2(0)) , kp2(1)
   Response.Write("The value of key "&Trim(kp2(0))&" is: " & d.Item(Trim(kp2(0))) &"<br />")
Next

Response.Write("<hr/>Or anywhere else <br/>The value of key2 is: " & d.Item("key2"))
```

Here I'm using the Scripting.Dictionary object that is used to store information in key/value pairs (referred to as key and item) as any other Dictionary in many other languages.